# Integrate 1D-Odometry into EKF

Tags: navigation, ekf, odometry, encoder, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have an [Ackermann-steering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_steering_geometry) style robot whose [tri-phase motor encoder](https://engineering.purdue.edu/%7Eee323/index.php?p=lab7a) I read. I would like to use this information as odometry with an [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization#ekf_localization_node) EKF node. The EKF fuses IMU yaw successfully already.

I build an [PoseWithCovarianceStamped](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseWithCovarianceStamped.html) (which is expected by the EKF node) in my custom node. But I'm confused about how I should integrate my position, since the encoder tells only distance driven in base_link / X-direction (forward). I tried two approaches:

1. On every encoder tick, add a certain
   length vector oriented like the IMU
   orientation quaternion axis. The
   message header's frame_id is `odom`.
2. On each encoder tick, add a certain
   length along the X-axis. The
   message header's frame_id is `base_link`.

Also, I'm not sure how to configure the pose0 in the EKF. In the first case, I tried:

```
<param name="pose0_relative" value="true"/>    
<rosparam param="pose0_config">
  [true, true,  false,  # x, y, z, - we want x and y
  false, false, false,  # roll, pitch, yaw,
  false, false, false,  # vx, vy, vz,
  false, false, false,  # vroll, vpitch, vyaw,
  false, false, false]  # ax, ay, az
</rosparam>
```

And in the second case:

```
<param name="pose0_differential" value="true"/>    
<rosparam param="pose0_config">
  [true, false, false,  # x, y, z, - we want x from motor encoder
  false, false, false,  # roll, pitch, yaw,
  false, false, false,  # vx, vy, vz,
  false, false, false,  # vroll, vpitch, vyaw,
  false, false, false]  # ax, ay, az
</rosparam>
```

The first case doesn't work at all (nothing moves in rviz). The second case works really well -- In the direction the car faces when the odometry stack is launched; but not at all perpendicular to that.

How can I use my encoder information with the EKF?

Cheers
Laurenz

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224524/integrate-1d-odometry-into-ekf/) by [lalten](https://answers.ros.org/users/25550/lalten/) on ROS Answers with karma: 102 on 2016-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you look at [Coordinate Frames and Transforming Sensor Data](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization/Tutorials/Preparing%20Your%20Sensor%20Data#Coordinate_Frames_and_Transforming_Sensor_Data) you'll notice that pose data is interpreted relative to the world frame, while twist data is interpreted relative to the base_link frame.

One proper way of providing the data would thus be to compute the velocity from the encoder ticks and time between encoder reads and then provide a [nav_msgs/Odometry](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) message with the correct velocity set in the `twist/twist/linear/x` field. This can then be fed into robot_localization (the correct field has to be set to "true" for the config of course).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lalten](https://answers.ros.org/users/25550/lalten/) on 2016-01-20**:
Thanks a lot, that solved it!